# entity framework version issue

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have a wcf webservice called service1 in solution1
then i created another wcf webservice called service2 in solution2.
then in service2, i referenced service1.
I installed entity framework v5 in both service1 and service2. Then I run a function in service2 which call the function in service1. but i get an exception like:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)":"EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"}

Could anybody know how to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: run the function for service 1 directly and verify it works. If it does, go into service2 and get the version of the EF assembly. Compare this to the version in your web.config and make sure they're the same. If not, you either need to fix it in your web.config or uninstall / reinstall EF to the correct version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally, i copy paste all the content in the folder "package" from service1 to service2